# set default new text file line delimiter to Unix in spring STS IDE

Tags: eclipse, sts

How to set new text file line delimiter as Unix in Spring STS ? I am looking for setting that can apply for all workspace while IDE loading, not for each workspace.
Not expecting this answer:
Workspace: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> New text file line delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set default preferences for everything in the `plugin_customization.ini` file for the product. This file is normally in the main product plug-in directory.

The line separator preference is called `line.separator` in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` preferences, so the entry in the plugin_customization.ini file would be something like:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime/line.separator=\n
```

for Unix line separators. `\r\n` for Windows.